# Replacing strings and sorting in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace the strings in a pandas dataframe column, which is sucessful but I'm missing other rows, only the two modified strings with it's rows are kept in the DF. And one thing is left from there is to order the complete DF by the numbers from the third columns (Pos1, Pos3, Pos4)
(see desired output).

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [5614,4564,3314,3144,1214,4314],
        '2': ['banana','kiwi' ,'salsa','avocado','mix','juice'],
        '3': ['Pos1','Pos1','Pos3','Pos3','Pos1','Pos1']
        })

df = df[4:5].replace('Pos1', 'Pos3') 
# however this doesn't modify the original df but overwrites it with only two rows ( 1214   mix  Pos3, 4314 juice Pos3)


# regarding to locate the integers from 3rd column: 
for indx,row in df.iterrows():
     if row[3].isdigit() == True:
         #... sort_by(row[3]) 
         # but preserve the following order (check desired output)
```

```
Dataframe

    1       2       3
0   5614    banana  Pos1
1   4564    kiwi    Pos4
2   3314    salsa   Pos3
3   3144    avocado Pos3
4   1214    mix     Pos1
5   4314    juice   Pos1


Desired output:

    1       2       3
0   5614    banana  Pos1
1   3314    salsa   Pos3
2   3144    avocado Pos3
3   1214    mix     Pos3
4   4314    juice   Pos3
5   4564    kiwi    Pos4
```

Edited: order/sorting problem (doesn't preserve the exact order "inside"/group of Pos1's or Pos3's, but it'srather scattered)

Picture:
[image]

If you look at the picture the very first 10 items should have the exact same order as it was from the very beginning, but even these aren't in order: it's shuffled. it should be: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.. 10 but not 0,9,7,6,5,8,3,2,1 (these are all "Pos1")

Comment: I do not understand your sorting problem. What are you trying to sort by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [5614,4564,3314,3144,1214,4314],
        '2': ['banana','kiwi' ,'salsa','avocado','mix','juice'],
        '3': ['Pos1','Pos4','Pos3','Pos3','Pos1','Pos1']
        })
# replace strings only in column 3
df.loc[4:, '3'] = df.loc[ 4:,'3'].replace('Pos1', 'Pos3')
# sort values by column '3'
df = df.sort_values('3')
df
>>>
      1        2     3
0  5614   banana  Pos1
2  3314    salsa  Pos3
3  3144  avocado  Pos3
4  1214      mix  Pos3
5  4314    juice  Pos3
1  4564     kiwi  Pos4
```

This replaces all strings in '3' for all indecwes greater 4. Later it is sorted by this column (without reindexing).

If you want the index stay the same you have to use `df = df.sort_values('3', ignore_index=True)` for sorting.

**Update**

If you want to sort your DataFrame after an index greater 3, you have to slice first, then sort and the replace the values. Can look like this.

```
df.loc[3:] = df.loc[3:].sort_values('3').set_index(df.loc[3:].index)
```

It is important to call `set_index` because if you dont do this, the right hand side start by `0` again and you will fill your DataFrame with NaN values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've managed to do everything except sorting, with or without indexing no success. Since my df is much bigger and I have duplicate rows for some reason duplicates are not after each other as it was before sorting, however, the order itself just by looking at 3rd col, it is fine, but the order must be preserved inside of the sequence of the same Pos# numbers.

Comment: Can you please update your question to point out the problem you have? How does such group of #Pos numbers look like?

Comment: I've updated the question and I've given a picture with an explanation. Sorry, I can't disclose the information inside the dataframe that's why I'm only showing the order problem. Hope you can still see the issue. EDIT: I did try with ignore_index=True/False as well same result.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do with seeing only the index. I hope my update helps. If not please create a minimal example with fake data, if you can't show us your real data.

Answer (score 0):

The replace row should be:

```
df[4:5] = df[4:5].replace('Pos1', 'Pos3')
```

The problem with your original code was that it passes only [4:5] to df.

Comment: Correct, I forgot it that's why it was confusing me initially. Still missing the sorting part. imagine as if i would copy-paste all the rows from pos3 and drag-drop it after the last pos1 row